# Birkat Halevana vs. Kiddush Levana

Tags: etymology, kiddush-levanah

Where are the origins of calling this Beracha "Kiddush" Levana, and what does it mean?

I have seen that Rabbi Yosef Qafih in his commentary to Maimonides’s Guide for the Perplexed (Vol. 2 Chapter 5 note 15) points out that all earlier sources call this blessing either Birkat Hayarech or Birkat Halevana - not Kiddush Levana “as some sects of Israel mistakenly call it”.

Comment: Does it matter what people call it? How can a conventional name be mistaken?

Comment: Does not make an halachik difference - but I want to know how this conventional name came about!